# Exporting Flash/Actionscript animation to PNGs and transform data?

Tags: python, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

We're working on a project right now where our animator is creating animations in Flash (the tool in which he's most comfortable) which we need to export for our application. He's using separate sprites (for a person, we'd use eyes, mouth, hair, feet, etc.) and transforming them appropriately. So, if his head is rocking back and forth, one frame might be normal, one might be rotated 20°, another normal, and another -20°, and so on.

What we need is to export all of the sprites used in the animation, along with the transform data for each object in each frame.

Unfortunately, the animation is being done in Actionscript, which complicates things somewhat, and because we're using sprite components that we use in multiple places, we want each component of the animation exported separately.

As long as we can get it into some kind of more easily parse-able format, we should be fine, but we're not familiar enough with Flash, in a technical sense, to know where to start looking. Solutions in Python would be preferred, since that's the language we're all working in.

Comment: There is an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396992/export-animation-data-from-flash

Answer (score 0):

The first nightmare would be nested symbols. Try some basics using onEnterFrame and see if you can iterate (is there a mechanism to discover all the stage members) the symbols/sprites on the stage and get their properties.